# Python/Pandas - Rearrange string from column value

Tags: python, pandas, date

I would need to rearrange the column value on column: "Quarter" . Expected output should be as in column:"new_Quarter"

[image]

I got the column:"Quarter" from column:"Date" using the below code

```
df['Quarter'] = pd.PeriodIndex(df['Date'], freq='Q')
```

I tried to get the target column:"new_Quarter" using below code but getting an error

```
df['new_Quarter'] = q['Quarter'].str.slice(4,6) + ' ' + q['Quarter'].str.slice(2,4)
```

> TypeError: ufunc 'add' did not contain a loop with signature matching types dtype('

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use [`strftime`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.strftime.html)

```
df['new_Quarter'] = df.Quarter.dt.strftime('Q%q %y')
```

As a side note, the column `Quarter` can also be simply created using [`to_period`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.to_period.html)

```
df['Quarter'] = df.Date.dt.to_period('Q')
```

---

```
        Date Quarter new_Quarter
0 2019-09-18  2019Q3       Q3 19
1 2019-03-18  2019Q1       Q1 19
2 2019-05-13  2019Q2       Q2 19
```